# Why only String type arguments in java main method

Tags: java

I want to know the reason behind allowing only String type arguments and not other primitive types. Why the developers have created it in that way

Comment: How can you pass another type into a program? `someprogram.exe 1 somestring 26-07-2011`, they are all strings.

Answer (score 11):

Pretty much all common operating systems provide only simple strings as the arguments to newly launched processes.

The decision to do the same for `main` simply mirrors the most common interface.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments were for command-line arguments, strings are what the user enters at the command line. Seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass arguments from a console (cmd.exe for instance), the command entered is in fact a String (eg: "java -jar myApp.jar" & your arg1, arg2.. etc)

Since you can enter numeric arguments, string arguments, it takes it all as a String since (almost) everything can be interpreted as characters.

You can parse a String as ints, floats, etc. anyway so where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Any args that you pass to the process can be represented as a `String`. This is not true of the other primitive types, so `String` is really the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the Java `main` method was taken from C++ (with slight improvements to make it more type-safe), to make it easier for C/C++ developers to pick up Java. C++'s `main` in turn was inherited from C. Which was probably inherited (or at least influenced by) B and BCPL, its predecessors. Which probably used string parameters for the reasons explained in other answers.

Comment: Note that there is a significant change: the Java `main` method does not have a return value!